# Internet Explorer 11 Browser session becoming corrupt

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I'm having an issue with a random set of users running Windows 10 and IE11. When the issue occurs the user are in an IE 11 browser session and will see among other things that selected div sections will scroll text but the textboxes and dropdowns will remain static within that div. 
The current fix is to start a new browser session not just a new window. Currently this only occurring in about 15-20 out of 700 users. Pages are running with doc mode Edge and user agent default. 
I realize this is a rather sparse explanation but that is what I have so far. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what could be causing the issue or a tool that would allow further investigation into the browser session?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume that this issue is not related with website and issue is with IE browser.

I suggest you to check for latest Windows and IE related updates. If any new updates are available than try to install new updates and again check for the issue.

If no any new updates available than try to reset the Internet Explorer browser to check whether it fix the issue or not.

If issue persist than you can try to unchecked the Internet Explorer option from **Turn Windows features on or off** and again try to check that option to add the IE again.

[image]

Let us know about your testing results. If issue persist than we can try to provide further suggestions.